# python string.split() and loops

Tags: python, string, for-loop

disclaimer im new to python 
i need to split a string input send if to a function that substitutes a character in the string with a different character (like a substitution cipher) but i just dont know how to go about this

```
print('Welcome to the encryption protocol for top secret governemt cover ups')
string=input('whats your message?')
def encrypt(string):
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"
    sub_alpha = "pokmenliuytrwqazxcvsdfgbhn"

index=0
while index < len(string):
    letter=string[index]
```

im not really sure what im doing im really bad at python, this has had me stumped for 3 days now ive reviewed my course material and tried videos on youtube im probably just really really dumb

Answer (score 1):

I think the key piece of knowledge you're missing is that strings are iterable. So you can do things like:

```
for c in "FOO":
    print(c)
    # prints "F\nO\nO\n"
```

And you can find the index of a character within a string with [str.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index). So you can build up your cyphertext like this:

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz "
cypher = "pokmenliuytrw qazxcvsdfgbhn"
plaintext = "some string"
cyphertext = ""
for c in plaintext:
    char_index = alpha.index(c)
    cyphertext += cypher[char_index]
```

You can also iterate over things inline - this is called a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). So to transform your string you can do this instead of using the `for` loop:

```
cyphertext = "".join(cypher[alpha.index(c)] for c in plaintext)
```

The example above uses the [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function to concatenate each character of cyphertext.

Comment: this works nicely ill try to split it into functions my self thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that asks the question and then iterates through each letter, finding the index in the alpha key, and replacing it with the sub_alpha key equivalent.
Note this example also checks if it should be lowercase or uppercase.
EDIT: if the input character does not have a valid cipher, it doesn't get altered.
EDIT 2: expanded answer to convert both forwards and backwards.

```
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"
sub_alpha = "pokmenliuytrwqazxcvsdfgbhn"

def encrypt(in_char):   
    is_lower_case = in_char.islower()
    index = alpha.find(in_char.lower())

    if index < 0:
        return in_char
    elif is_lower_case:
        return sub_alpha[index]
    else:
        return sub_alpha[index].upper()

def decrypt(in_char):
    is_lower_case = in_char.islower()
    index = sub_alpha.find(in_char.lower())

    if index < 0:
        return in_char
    elif is_lower_case:
        return alpha[index]
    else:
        return alpha[index].upper()

print('Welcome to the encryption protocol for top secret governemt cover ups')
input_str=input('whats your message? ')
output_str=""

for letter in input_str:
    output_str += encrypt(letter)

print("Encrypted: ")
print(output_str)

input_str=""
for letter in output_str:
    input_str+= decrypt(letter)

print("Decrypted: ")
print(input_str)
```

Comment: i get this error: NameError: output_str not defined

Comment: @irvdtcc you haven't posted the error, but I'm guessing it is because you haven't got a complete key, e.g if you have a space then it doesn't know what to turn that into. I'll edit the answer to fix that :)

Comment: @irvdtcc try this, better?

Comment: @irvdtcc I just saw your edit. Try using the code I posted, I added a line which declares output_str. I didn't just change the encrypt function.

Comment: this works nicely!  what did the error mean by the way?

Comment: `NameError: output_str not defined` just means that the output_str variable hadn't been created. It could easily be caused just by forgetting the `output_str=""` line. The other error I was referring to is caused by using `index = alpha.index(in_char.lower())` instead of `index = alpha.find(in_char.lower())`. index will cause an error if it doesn't find what we're looking for, but find will just return -1

Comment: ive expanded this so that it will revert back to English. i get some errors  for this line, i have separated it so that main calls decrypt is its own function but i get error for this  function

Comment: def decrypt(output_str):
    eng=""
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"
    sub_alpha = "pokmenliuytrwqazxcvsdfgbhn"
    is_lower_case = in_char.islower()
    index = sub_alpha.find(in_char.lower())
    if index < 0:
        return in_char
    elif is_lower_case:
        return _alpha[index]
    else:
        return alpha[index].upper()


    for letter in output_str:
        output_str += decrypt(letter)

Comment: I think I can spot an error where you refer to `in_char` but your input parameter is now called `output_str`. Another error is you refer to `_alpha` instead of `alpha`. I have edited my answer to include both forwards and backwards conversion.